# Compare two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am using 3D vector as key in C++ map containers.For which I have to implement comparison of two vectors. I used magnitude to compare vectors. But problem arises when two vectors are different but their magnitudes are same, which is resulting in overwriting of keys in C++ map container.

You can find small snipped of implementation.

```
class Vector3f
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    double magnitude() const { return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z); }
}
std::map<Vector3f, std::vector<int>, Vector3fCompare> vector_index;

struct Vector3fCompare
{
    bool operator() (const Vector3f& lhs, const Vector3f& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.magnitude() < rhs.magnitude();
    }
};
```

Is there any way to compare two vectors?

Comment: This is not a math question, but a programming question. You should ask this over at Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: [Lovsovs] I am asking is there any measure to compare n dimension vectors

Comment: @nbsrujan You can define your own measure, say, if the magnitude is equal, then check the $\hat{i}$ component. If that's equal, check the $\hat{j}$ component. If that's also equal, then, the vectors are identical.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Currently I am using Euclidean distance, is there any straight formula to compare two n-dimensional vectors

Comment: Take the difference of the two vectors then find its magnitude. If that is 0 then they are the same.

Comment: Strangely enough there isn't a migration option to Stack Overflow…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here sole purpose to compare two vectors is to construct a C++ map. So comparing two vectors in [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using three dimensional vectors as a lookup key the only way to avoid overwriting is to check them for equality: all three components must be the same. That's probably faster than computing the magnitude or the magnitude of their difference (as @Paul suggests).

If the components are floating point values that come from a computation and not integers you may still have a problem caused by roundoff error.

PS If you do use the magnitude only for comparison purposes you can save time by using its square. Don't bother with the square root.